# Meteor + PhantomJS how to make it work

Tags: meteor, phantomjs, meteorite

im trying to install PhantomJS in a MeteorApp.

I have done those step:

Add the npm package

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Run meteor to let the npm package to pre-initialise

```
meteor
```

A file packages.json has been created at the root. Edit it to:

```
{
  "phantomjs": "1.9.13"
}
```

A this point everything seem to work. But i try to test with this exemple that ive found here :
https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-phantomjs

But i dont understand where to put my phantomDriver.js

Why is phantomDriver.js is in assets/app/phantomDriver.js... but after, they say to create the file in ./private/phantomDriver.js...

Thank for clear explication :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development mode you create the file in `/private/phantomDriver.js`. When you build a meteor app it refactors everything into an application bundle which can be run.

After meteor builds your app it stores stuff from `private` into `assets`. For phantomjs to execute this file it needs to look in this directory. You don't have to create it. This is how meteor works internally.

If you look in your `.meteor/local/build/programs/server` directory the `assets` directory is there with anything you placed in `private`.

From the context of where your meteor code runs (the server directory above) the `assets` directory runs from this directory when your project is running.

Keep in mind when you deploy your app it loses its entire project structure and becomes something else. Gadi's phantomjs project is designed to work in production environments too.

TLDR; Don't worry about the `assets` directory, keep your file in `/private/phantomDriver.js`. Meteor should take care of the rest.